# Power button not working on Asus Zenfone 5

Tags: power-on

I bought an Asus Zenfone a few days ago and it was working well for 2 daysT the system asked to install an update and I agreed and installed it. Now the power button is not working at all.

Could it be a hardware or software issue? What should I do?

Device information:
Model Number : ASUS_T00J
Android Version : 4.3
Software Build Number : ASUS_T00J_WW_user_1.18.40.9_20140827_0215

Comment: As it's still new, your best bet is to take it back to the shop

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Was working fine until the update.

To fix it I had to reset the phone: Settings/Backup & reset. Make sure all of your data is backed up before you do it. After the reset it is working fine.

I considered running it flat & see if it would work on restart but if it didn't then it would be a lot harder to reset - manually through pc.

Hope this helps.

**Update**

I changed my case during this process & have just changed it back. Same symptoms started happening - it seems that the power button on the case is placing too much pressure on the switch & by picking up or moving the phone it is sometimes enough to activate the button. Changing the case back & everything works fine again.

My original case was fine. The problem one was the asus flip cover case. Looking inside at the buttons I noticed that the materials were slightly different.

I would suggest trying your phone without any case & see if you still get problems.